# Centering float:left thing vertically

Tags: css

I can't figure it out how to center float:left object vertically. 
I imagine that I could set the position of this menu bar vertically (The height of Y-axis) I think that would be the answer

[image]

// html part

```
 <div class="menu_simple">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">One</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Two</a></li>

        </ul>
```

//css

```
.menu_simple ul {
        float:left;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            width:100px;
            list-style-type: none;
            box-shadow: 5px 8px 5px #888888;


        }

        .menu_simple ul li a {
            border: 1px solid #0066cc;
            text-decoration: none;
            color: white;
            padding: 10.5px 11px;
            background-color: #3b3b3b;
            display:block;
        }

        .menu_simple ul li a:visited {
            color: white;
        }

        .menu_simple ul li a:hover, .menu_simple ul li .current {
            color: white;
            background-color: #5FD367;
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/t175g4z5/)

First you set `position: absolute` for the menu div, then set `top` to 50% and the transform option to -50%.

Source: https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/

Hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

Use the CSS [position property](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp).

Set the page hold, in your case the `<body>` to `position: relative;` and the part you wish to move, in your case; `.menu_simple` to the following:

```
.menu_simple {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Flexbox works nicely for this type of thing:
http://codepen.io/simply-simpy/pen/rVwXyz
`menu_simple {
  display:flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: center;
  height: 500px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}`